# how to select all the values in hive with distinct of 2 columns in hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table that looks like this (total 460 columns)

```
 colA   colB ....... ce_id filename ......... dt
  v      j            4     gg                40
  v      j            5     gg                55
  f      r            4     gg                40
  t      y            7     yy                32
  a      e            5     ee                43
```

now i need to write a query that selects all the data using distinct of 2 colunms  with ce_id and filename

my expected output

```
 colA   colB ....... ce_id filename ......... dt
  v      j            4     gg                40
  v      j            5     gg                55
  t      y            7     yy                32
  a      e            5     ee                43
```

anyone can guide me how to select all the data with 2 distinct value

Comment: Do you care which row you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `row_number()` does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ce_id, filename order by dt) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You don't specify *which* row you want.  The above formulation returns the one with the smallest value of `dt`.  The `order by` controls the "which".